# Webkit browser's inspector is missing a few things

Tags: ubuntu, webkit, gtk, gtk3

I'm using a Webkit browser inspector like [this](https://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/source/browse/trunk/demos/inspector.py?r=142).

When I run it in Ubuntu 12.10, I'm getting errors when using the inspector. For example:

```
** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Go to line" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Filter" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Search Previous" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Search Next" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "α:" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "%d of %d" not found.


(geany:2487): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_error_trap_pop: assertion `gdk_error_traps != NULL' failed
** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Sources Panel" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Toggle breakpoint" not found.

** Message: console message: file:///usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webinspector/UIString.js @42: Localized string "Painting" not found.
```

I also noticed the breadcrumb/slider bar doesn't show when you have the console in the lower half:

[image: Blank bar]

I don't remember this in earlier versions, and when I use the GTK3 version (`from gi.repository import WebKit` etc) it has a similar problem and is even worse, scrollbars don't have arrows at top and bottom. Am I missing a step on initializing the Webkit inspector or English locale for it?

I would like to debug this issue, but since the inspector object isn't a webview object, I'm not sure I can add an inspector to the inspector? (like how you can use F12 when the inspector is its own window in Chrome/Chromium, which lets you debug that inspector). It should be possible, but [maybe not with pyGTK](http://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-gtk@lists.webkit.org/msg01018.html)?

**Update:**
I tested this on 12.04 Ubuntu and didn't notice the problem above. I reported a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pywebkitgtk/+bug/1073395). Is this a conflict with some package in every 12.10 computer, or do I have my configuration set up incorrectly?

**Update:**
The same problem is happening in 13.04.

Comment: It may even be a problem with the themes that are being available for your gtk libraries. I wouldn't be surprised if that were the case, given the constant flux of changes in gtk. What happens when you try to change the theme of the environment and then restart the application (which I guess is tunesviewer, right?).

Comment: I'm getting the same problem no matter the GTK theme. The problem persists in Tunesviewer as well as any Python-based Webkit view. (even a simple example such as this: http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2012/04/making-gtkwebkit-inspector-and-enable.html )

Comment: Humm, strange. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/OnvH0.png) is what I see in my pure Debian system.

Comment: @rbrito can you check which version of gtk and python-webkit-gtk this was working on? Also, which version of webkit is it? (`navigator.userAgent` will give you Webkit/versionnumber)

Comment: It's also happening in Midori (but not Chromium), so I don't think anything's wrong in Python-GTK.

Comment: I still don't see the problem with Midori in Debian's unstable as of Aug 20. Do you want a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, I'd like a list of libraries/versions that work, to know where to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Google Chrome some previous versions.
The only thing that solved it was restart the web inspector.